# Generate a html file with mathjax expressions and convert it to a pdf with html2pdf

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, mathjax, html2pdf

I have to print out a series of mathematical expressions in a PDF. The expressions are generated by a php function:

```
<?php

$taskID=$_GET['taskID'];
$pages=GetPDFContent($taskID);
include(__DIR__.'/../../html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','de');
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($pages);
$html2pdf->Output("$taskID.pdf");


function GetPDFContent($taskID){
    include("core/lib/connection/db.php");

    [...]

    $html="<page pageset:'new'> 
    <page_header> 
<img src='http://www.mathup.de/images/MathUp_langDE.png' style='width:150px;' id='logoIMG' alt='Logo MathUp'>
    </page_header> 
    <page_footer> 
&copy; $Jahr Peter Mayer
    </page_footer> 
    <div class='PDFContentHeight' style='margin:50px;'>
$$5\\cdot4=20$$
    </div>  
</page><script>MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);</script>";

    return $html; } 
?>
```

I tried to parse the expression with `<script>MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);</script>`
but unfortunately this won't work.

Can anyone help me to parse the expression?

Comment: I'm not familiar with html2pdf, but the `<script>` tag contains Javascript, so my first guess would be that html2pdf does not handle Javascript.

Comment: I took at look at the GitHub page and found this example: https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/blob/master/examples/js1.php